# Editing associated models the rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models

I have a model "Student" and every student has_many parents (a mother and a father in the parents table). In my UI I want to be able to add the parents and the student on the same page. So when I click on "Add student" the view 'students/new' is rendered. In this view I have the regular stuff for adding a student (`<% form_for @student....`) so far so good. But now I also want to provide the form for adding a mother and a father for this student on the same page. I know I could place a link to 'parents/new' somewhere but that is not really user-friendly in my opinion.

What are my options and what would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be using `nested_forms` with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` like below

```
#student.rb
Class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :parents
accepts_nested_attributes_for :parents
end

#students_controller.rb

def new
@student = Student.new
@student.parents.build
end

def create
@student = Student.new(student_params)
if @student.save
redirect_to @student
else
render 'new'
end

private

def student_params
params.require(:student).permit(:id, :student_attr_1, :student_attrr_2, parents_attributes: [:id, :father, :mother])
end

#students/new

<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
---student code here ---
<%= f.fields_for :parents do |p| %>
<%= p.label :father, :class => "control-label" %>
<%= p.text_field :father %>
<%= p.label :fmother, :class => "control-label" %>
<%= p.text_field :mother %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This approach seemed weird to me as it is not very intuitive to look for the 'new' action of the parents model in the students_controller. But I guess thats the way to go for.

Comment: Well then nested_forms it is! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `form` you can add `fields_for` helper

```
<%= fields_for @student.father do |father| %>
  <% father.text_field :name %> # will be appropriate father name
  ....
<% end %>
```

Check also [rails fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `ObjectForm` concept:

[Here is one good article about this pattern.](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)

Here's an introduction to the implementation:

```
Class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parents
end

class CompleteStudentForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_acessor :name, :age #student attributes
  attr_accessor :father_name, :mother_name #assuming that Parent model has only the :name attribute

  validates_presence_of :name, :age
  # simply add custom validation messages for fields
  validates_presence_of :father_name, message: 'Fill your father name'
  validates_presence_of :mother_name, message: 'Fill your mother name'

  def save
    persist! if valid?
  end

  private
  def persist!
    student = Student.new(name: @name, age: @age)
    student.parents << Parent.new(name: @father_name)
    student.parents << Parent.new(name: @mother_name)
    student.save!
  end
end


class StudentController 

  def create
    @student = CompleteStudentForm.new(params[:complete_student_form])

    if @student.save
      redirect_to :show, @student
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think I'll go with nested forms but for bigger projects or other needs this solution might be the better fit.